# My console is saying that it terminated a file but it never wrote the words that I needed in the console

Tags: java, eclipse, println

I'm having trouble with a script that I wrote. My code is :

```
public void run() {
    init();
    while (true) {
        update();
        render();
    }
}

private void update() {
    System.out.println("Updating");
}

private void render( ) {
    System.out.println("Rendering");
}
```

When I hit run all it says is that it terminated the file javaw.exe. It doesn't output the text in the quotes. Please help by fixing what is wrong

Comment: is the while reached? Or does the script exit in the init function? You can find out by strategically adding some more print statements.

Comment: What does init() do?  What is calling this?  Your while-loop is an endless loop - so I'm skeptical it is being executed if your program is terminating normally.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this line after your impressions and validate that you are entering the if

```
private void render( ) {
System.out.println("Rendering");
Console.ReadKey();
```

}

Comment: That is more of a debugging experiment proposal than an answer. It should better be in a comment. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead